# Scala implicit scope requires double import

Tags: scala

I can't see why in the following code the import (`import b._`) that pulls in the `implicit def` must appear in both position 1 and position 2 for it to work.

```
package a {
  abstract class Base {}
}

package b {
  import a._

  class Derived(i: Int) extends Base {}

  object b {
    implicit def i2d(i: Int): Derived = new Derived(i)
  }
}

import a._
// position 1
import b._

object test extends App {
  // position 2  
  import b._

  def doIt(base: Base) {
    println("works")
  }

  doIt(1)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At position 1 you are importing everything from the *package* b and at position 2 you are importing everything from the *object* b, which includes the implicit def. You could just `import b.b._` at position 2.

Comment: Thanks, but your suggestion doesn't work because `b.b` is a `package object` and so trying that gives the error `value b is not a member of object b.b`.  Besides which, that doesn't answer why importing it solely at position 1 doesn't work if it is supposed to import everything?  This code only works with both imports.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing which leads you to these conclusions, but a) b is not a package object and b) he's completely correct.  Just import b.b._, at position 1 or 2, doesn't matter.  If it doesn't compile, you're either not using the code you've shown or not using current scala.

Comment: Apologies, I thought it was a `package object` but I must have missed something there, which leaves me confused as to how it works in the first place. However I am using the code shown and Scala 2.9.0 with SBT 0.7.7, all on OSX and using `import b.b._` gives the error message above.

Comment: @Jay, Could you post the exact code that gives you the error `value b is not a member of object b.b`? Maybe you're doing something like `import b._` (*this brings object `b` within package `b` into scope*), and then `import b.b._` (*now you're trying to access another `b` from within `object b.b`*). The error message basically says there doesn't exist `b.b.b`.

Comment: @Kipton - thank you, that explains it perfectly.  As you guessed, I was still doing both imports having changed one to the direct object import as explained by Kim.